# Sum of $X_n$ independently distributed with $X_n\sim\text{Exp}(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independently distributed with $X_n\sim\text{Exp}(n)$ and let $a_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}<\infty.$

> Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nX_n$ converges almost surely.

My first instinct was to use the Lindeberg-Feller CLT. But I want almost surely convergence. I can't use Kolmogorov's two-series theorem or Kolmogorov's three-series theorem because the $X_n$ are not i.i.d.

I know that $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E[a_n^2X_n^2] = \frac 12\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^2<\infty.$$
And $$\sqrt{n}\frac{S_n-\frac{\ln n}{n}}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}}\overset{n\to\infty}{\implies}\mathcal N(0,1).$$
What can I do?

Comment: Isn't only independence required for Kolmogorov's three-series test?

Comment: Oh that is true ... Thank you @GiorgosGiapitzakis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Kolmogorov's two-series theorem because only independence is necessary. So we have
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb E[a_nX_n]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\mathbb E[X_n]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}<\infty$$
because of the conditions we impose on the $a_n$. Now because $a_n>0$ we see that $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb V[a_nX_n]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2\mathbb V[X_n]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n^2}{n^2}\leqslant \left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}\right]^2 <\infty.$$
Therefore is follows, that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges almost surely.